# Put proper CSS for dynamic checkboxes - Spring MVC

Tags: css, jsp, spring-mvc

This is a trivial question but I am quite new to this and please deal with it.

I am using `Spring MVC` and following is the code for checkbox population:

```
<form:checkboxes items="${evaluateAttributeList}" path="evaluateAttribute"/>
<span id="availmsg" style="display:none"></span>
<form:errors path="evaluateAttribute" cssClass="error"/>
```

I am passing `evaluateAttributeList` from the `Controller` and its populating fine.

I understand that putting a `< p >` or `< br >` will make one in each line.

I want to arrange them in proper order (ie. two checkboxes per line). What tweaking do I need to do on jsp side?

What changes do I need to make in the JSP so that a CSS is being used for all the checkboxes rather than all as a whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of Googling led me to this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/).

My best guess is that you will have to use a combination of `form:checkboxes` and `form:checkbox` within `<td>`s and `<tr>`s of an html `<table>`

Comment: Thanks Sachin! But this is the link I took help from! :) How can we put form:checkbox in dynamic page? Even this link doesn't do this.

Comment: I would put `form:checkbox` inside `c:forEach`. If thats what you mean by dynamic.